# Google Maps plugin for QtLocation. QtLocation/private/qgeotiledmappingmanagerengine_p.h: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, google-maps, plugins, qml, qtlocation

I'm trying to display Google Map in my Qt Quick Application by a plugin for QtLocation from this repo https://github.com/vladest/googlemaps?tab=readme-ov-file#google-maps-plugin-for-qtlocation

The program throw this error: 1, "The geoservices provider is not supported"

Just wondering if I'm using the plugin correctly.

I'm using Qt 6.5.1 and here are what I have done:

1. gh repo clone vladest/googlemaps in Qt/6.5.1/Src/qtlocation/src/plugins/geoservices folder

2. In CMakeLists.txt of the same folder:

```
add_subdirectory(itemsoverlay)
if(QT_FEATURE_geoservices_osm)
    add_subdirectory(osm)
endif()
if(QT_FEATURE_geoservices_esri)
    add_subdirectory(esri)
endif()
if(QT_FEATURE_geoservices_mapbox)
    add_subdirectory(mapbox)
endif()
if(QT_FEATURE_geoservices_nokia)
    add_subdirectory(nokia)
endif()

//added by me
if(QT_FEATURE_geoservices_googlemaps)
    add_subdirectory(googlemaps)
endif()
```

3. My Qml file look like this:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtLocation
import QtPositioning

Rectangle{
    anchors.left: parent.left
    width: parent.width / 5 * 4
    height: parent.height
    MapView{
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true

        Plugin {
            id: mapPlugin
            name: "googlemaps"
        }

        Map {
            id: map
            anchors.fill: parent
            plugin: mapPlugin
            center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
            zoomLevel: 14
            property geoCoordinate startCentroid
        }
    }
}
```

I have also try to use Qt 5.15.2 with similar steps (step 2 - add subdirectory in geoservices.pro file) and it throw the same error.

Comment: You don't have to add it to the cmakelists but compile the plugin and install it

Comment: Use qmake and make install

Comment: @eyllanesc . Thanks for your comment! I'm supper new to qt so could you please guild me step by step? Really appreciate it.

Comment: From what I'm understand, I should cd to the googlemaps repo, and do qmake and make there.

Comment: After I run make, I get this issue similar to this: https://github.com/vladest/googlemaps/issues/39 . I already check the QtLocation folder and it don't have the "private" folder.

Comment: I think the plugin is incompatible with Qt6

Comment: @eyllanesc , I have successfully install it with qt 6. Turn out the problem it with my current qt version for qmake. It doesn't have the "QtLocation/private" folder some how. I changed it to other qt version (6.5 or 5.15) which have the folder I mention above and it's working now. Thanks for your help anyway!